# Can't splice an item from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js, javascript-objects

I am writing a Discord bot, a part of which is an array of objects stored in JSON file. The user will be able to add and remove objects from the array with different commands. Each object in the array has two properties: `{"string":"test","count":0}`

I have some code which successfully adds objects to the array:

```
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('config.json');
let blacklist = JSON.parse(rawdata);

var newWord = {"string": args[3], "count": 0}
blacklist.words.push(newWord);

let data = JSON.stringify(blacklist);
fs.writeFileSync('config.json', data);
```

I have also written some code which removes objects from the array:

```
var remove = false;
for (i = 0; i < blacklist.words.length; i++) {
  if (blacklist.words[i].string === args[3]) {
    blacklist.words.splice(i, 1);
    var removed = true;
  }
}

if (removed) {
  message.reply(
    "the word `" +
      args[3] +
      "` has been successfully remove from your blacklist!"
  );
} else {
  message.reply(
    "I couldn't find the word `" + args[3] + "` on your blacklist!"
  );
}
```

The problem is, is that the code to add an object to this array works fine, however the code to remove objects doesn't. When I send the command to remove an object, the bot replies with `"the word`" + args[3] + "`has been successfully remove from your blacklist!"` which makes me think the code is running successfully, but not actually working.

Comment: _but not actually working_ what you mean with "not working"?

Comment: @Berto99 when I run the command, I check the `config.json` and the object that I supposedly removed is still in the file.

Comment: Probably you need to write back the object on the file, no?

Comment: Ah yes, of course, thank you. I am so stupid sometimes xD

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `removed` was redeclared inside the for a loop.

I have also added break so you don't need to traverse an entire array even after getting the result

```
var remove = false;
for (i = 0; i < blacklist.words.length; i++) {
    if (blacklist.words[i].string === args[3]) {
        blacklist.words.splice(i, 1);
        removed = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (removed) {
    message.reply("the word `" + args[3] + "` has been successfully remove from your blacklist!");
} else {
    message.reply("I couldn't find the word `" + args[3] + "` on your blacklist!");
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: added explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES5, you can use filter function

```
const filteredBlackList = blacklist.words.filter((item) => item.string !== args[3]);

var remove = false;
if (blacklist.words.length !== filteredBlackList.length) {
   remove = true;
}

if (removed) {
  message.reply("the word `" + args[3] + "` has been successfully remove from 
  your blacklist!");
} else {
  message.reply("I couldn't find the word `" + args[3] + "` on your 
  blacklist!");
}
```